# what is the correct use of "when vs If"?

Tags: conditionals, when

Stop work and initiate emergency response when unplanned contact with a buried facility occurs. OR 
Stop work and initiate emergency response if unplanned contact with a buried facility occurs.

Comment: The grammar aside, the meaning of the sentence is quite strange.

Answer (score 1):

According to definition 2 for "when" and 1a for "if" as listed below, the words may be used interchangeably.

It should be noted however that there is the phrase "when, not if" which is used to denote the inevitability of something, which may or may not be what you're looking for.

**TL;DR**

Both are valid, but using "when" might be interpreted as something that *will* happen, while "if" leaves the possibility of something not happening open.

[Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when) definitions for the conjunction "when" are

> **a :** at or during the time that : while
>
> *went fishing when he was a boy*
>
> **b :** just at the moment that
>
> *stop writing when the bell rings*
>
> **c :** at any or every time that
>
> *when he listens to music, he falls asleep*
>
> **2 :** in the event that : if
>
> *a contestant is disqualified when he disobeys the rules*
>
> **3a :** considering that
>
> *why use water at all when you can drown in it— Stuart Chase*
>
> **b :** in spite of the fact that : although
>
> *quit politics when I might have had a great career in it*
>
> **4 :** the time or occasion at or in which
>
> *tomorrow is when we must decide humor is when you laugh*

and those for the conjunction "if" are

> **1a :** in the event that
>
> **b :** allowing that
>
> **c :** on the assumption that
>
> **d :** on condition that
>
> **2 :** whether
>
> *asked if the mail had come*
>
> *I doubt if I'll pass the course*
>
> **3** —used as a function word to introduce an exclamation expressing a wish
>
> *if it would only rain*
>
> **4 :** even though : although perhaps
>
> *an interesting if untenable argument*
>
> **5 :** and perhaps not even
>
> *few if any changes are expected*
>
> —often used with not
>
> *difficult if not impossible*